Futuristic show/film about an empire and rebels where the empire rigs a rebel to explode
My aunt used to record shows on television and send them to my family (we didn't have TV reception), and that meant setting the recorder for 3-5 min before a start time and ending 3-5 min after the end time. I saw the first few minutes of either a show or a movie and I was curious as to what it was and how it ended. I will say what I remember.
It looked like it was trying to capitalize on Star Wars as it had a similar plot line and was very British. It had a title crawl that talked about an oppressive empire and a rebellion that formed to resist it but the empire had developed a new weapon to fight the rebels.
The scene then switched to some British guy who seemed to run a prison camp talking to a rebel prisoner. They were talking very cordially and politely in a stereotypically British way despite being enemies, and the guy in charge was asking the rebel everything and the rebel was answering everything as if under some kind of mind control. (The weapon appears to take control of the minds of the heroes.)
After the captured rebel tells the imperial everything the imperial wanted to know, the imperial lets him go back to the rebel base. The released rebel walks across what looks like some rocky, barren landscape somewhere in Scotland. The rest of the rebels see him and tell him to stop where he is in the open and he does.
Back at the prison, the man in charge is having tea and biscuits with another imperial officer. They see the released prisoner has stopped moving so they assume he is at the rebel camp. They push a button and the rebel prisoner explodes like a suicide bomber and takes a large chunk of the landscape with him. His rebel friends are a distance away so they survive, but have this sad look on their faces, not just because they lost a friend but because of the ruthlessness of the new imperial weapon of mind control and turning people into bombs.
Then the recording ended, like I said, it was commonplace to record just a little bit before the intended show and a little bit after. This show was a little bit after. Does anybody know what show or movie it was?

I wonder if it was Blake's 7

That might be it. Do you remember if there was an episode about mind controlling prisoners and making them bombs? I will add the show to my list of shows to watch.

Do you remember the show that was actually being recorded? Or a day/timeslot/station where it aired?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

For the geeks of us, the drug used to mind control prisoners was called Pylene-50. It neutralised rebel tendencies making the subject docile and obedient. The prisoner was ordered to return to the rebels, carrying a hidden bomb, and to set it off when they were there.

"Paul D. Waite" and "The Betpet" are correct. I was able to look up "Pylene-50" and from a wiki page trace it to "Blake's 7" episode 42 (that's S4 E3 for Americans) "traitor." I watched as much as I saw a long time ago and it was what I remember. I don't think the prisoner was the bomb but had a tracking device on him and the Federation fired a weapon at his location. How do I checkmark a correct answer? I see upvotes and flags for inappropriate answers.

This is a very close match to the Blake's 7 Episode "Traitor". It does feature "imperial" type officers interrogating a rebel and after said rebel is sent on his way the "imperials" do indeed chat and drink tea.
Apart from the opening crawl what you describe is a solid match for the first seven or eight minutes of the episode.
It sounds like you were not watching this in the UK so it's possible another broadcaster added an opening text crawl.
You can watch the episode on youtube here...



lets see if its what you remember

I concur. One of my all-time favourite shows and this question perfectly describes the episode "Traitor".

I'm still trying to get used to the format of this site, it's not like other forums. I saw your answer after I read the other comments. I literally commented above before I saw your post with the video link. I already watched the parts I saw and it is what I remember, the parts I got wrong were most likely mandala effects.
